# Xamarin Android and where to find System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an error code from a webexception and I want to get the error message that belongs to that code. In a Windows application I reference System.Web and use this code (and it works well):

```
System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription(errorCode)
```

Now I want to do the same thing in Xamarin and an Android application. But in which assembly can I find HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription? There is no System.Web in Xamarin but the documentation says System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription() se this link: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription/p/System.Int32/

Comment: Maybe you're on a PCL project?

Comment: That's not the case. I just copied this line of code from a complete different Windows application project. I know that some functions are in different assemblies using Windows .NET and Mono .NET, like HttpWebRequest (System.Web / System.Net)

Comment: Which type of project is it?

Comment: Now then you ask I'm getting unsure but I think it's an Android app. In what way is this important?

Comment: Because if it's a Xamarin Forms app your project IS a PCL project, so there are a ton of API's unavailable

Comment: Is it possible to see that somehow? I don't have any Using Xamarin.Forms in my code.

Comment: It-s not a "using", it's a type of project

Comment: I know that. But is it possible to see that afterwards you have created the project?